# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue on spark test cases

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mockito

I'm currently writing test cases for spark with mockito and I'm mocking a sparkContext which gets wholeTextFiles called on it. I have something like this

```
val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.makeRDD(Seq(("Java", 20000),
("Python", 100000), ("Scala", 3000)))
doReturn(rdd).when(mockContext).wholeTextFiles(testPath)
```

However, I keep getting an error saying wholeTextFiles is supposed to output an int

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: ParallelCollectionRDD cannot be returned by wholeTextFiles$default$2()
wholeTextFiles$default$2() should return int
```

I know this isn't the case, the spark docs say that wholeTextFiles returns an RDD object, any tips on how I can fix this? I can't have my doReturn be of type int, because then the rest of my function fails, since I turn the wholeTextFiles output into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this with some alternative approaches. It works just fine if I do the  Mockito.when() thenReturn pattern, but I decided to instead change the entire test case to start a local sparksession and load some sample files into an rdd instead, because that's a more in depth test of my function imo